# PPL and Intel media SDK

Tags: performance, concurrency, tbb, ppl

I would like to integrate the Intel QSV encoder in my project. There is a point in the Intel known limitations release note I like to be clarified:

> Using the Intel Media SDK in parallel with Intel® Threading Building Blocks could impact performance

Why does thread management impact the Intel QSV encoder?

My project doesn't use Intel TBB but uses the Microsoft concurrency runtime Parallel Paterns Library (PPL) technology. Would the PPL impact the Intel QSV performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer from Intel:

> I'm sorry the release notes are not very clear. Basically the
>   statement applies to the Media SDK SW codecs and boils down to the
>   fact that the SW codecs utilizes all available logical processor cores
>   when executing a workload. This is regardless of using threading
>   framework such as PPL or TBB, or generic threading. There is always
>   the possibility that the processor cores will be oversubscribed thus
>   potentially impacting performance. Media SDK currently has no
>   mechanism to control the number of internal threads for the SW codecs.